# Implement solr search in php website

Tags: php, solr

I have some confusion that how we can implement solr search in php website 
Php website is running on other server and solr is running on other server then how we can restart solr server from php website on time of searching?

I am using solr php client file to connect with solr search then how we can restart solr server automatic.
Please provide me any solution, 
Help me !!

Comment: it is very easy to learn. plenty of blogs are available online. it will hardly take 2 days to implement Apache Solr with your PHP projects, Keep Learning!

Comment: What do you mean by "restart Solr server automatic"? There is no need to restart a Solr server, and your question is far to general to say anything useful about what you're trying to do. Add concrete examples and what you've tried, and possibly what error messages you're getting!